# Can't verify CSRF token authenticity in Rails 6 with SSL nginx reverse proxy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssl, nginx, reverse-proxy

My purpose was to set up reverse proxy with caching static content for Rails 6 app. I have a form tag with a bunch of data to be passed by user (a lot of input, sensitive data too). Submitting form works fine until applying Let's Encrypt SSL. Look at my Nginx configuration file:

```
server {

        listen 443 ssl;
        listen [::]:443 ssl;

        server_name www.example.com example.com;

        ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem;
        ssl on;

        location / {
                proxy_cache form_cache;
                proxy_ignore_headers "Set-Cookie";
                proxy_hide_header "Set-Cookie";
                proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Ssl on;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $http_host;
        }
}

server {
        listen 8080;
        listen [::]:8080;

        server_name localhost;

        root /var/www/form/public;

        location ~ \.(jpe?g|png|gif|ico|svg|css|js|eot|webp|ttf|woff|woff2)$ {
           expires 1y;
           add_header Cache-Control public;

           add_header ETag "";
        }

        passenger_enabled on;
        passenger_app_env workspace;

        allow 127.0.0.1;
        deny all;
}
```

After submitting attempt response in my app log is:

```
Can't verify CSRF token authenticity.
  
ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken (ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken)
```

I'm very confused and no idea where to search. Is it any header need to be set up for proxy or any middleware configurations need to be made on Rails app side? Please, help.

Comment: If the token is the same ever time you request the page then you will have to update it dynamically because it's being cached. This blog post might help: https://www.fastly.com/blog/caching-uncacheable-csrf-security

Comment: Thank You, I've found solution: the problem was setting proxy headers:                 proxy_ignore_headers "Set-Cookie"; proxy_hide_header "Set-Cookie". These two removed Rails session cookie which is necessary to authenticate form send to application.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following to configuration

```
proxy_set_header origin 'http://www.example.com';
```